Directions for performing Achamanam
Is it true that one should not perform Achamanam while facing west? If so, why, and what is the proper way to perform Achamanam for sayam sandhya (at dusk) since we have to face west while performing it?

Face north during sayam sandhya while doing achamanam

See the following answer .. approved directions are East and North -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/28992/4732

In the book nitya karma Pooja prakash it is written north or east is ok

Nitya karma Pooja prakash pdf
